# Appodeal android example errors

Tags: android, libgdx

When I downloaded a Appodeal project and run it I got many popups (Error: xxxx not found) [this links](https://github.com/appodeal/appodeal-libgdx-demo)
After that it crashes showing this error in the log `FATAL EXCEPTION: Process: com.appodeal.test, PID: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.appodeal.ads.g.t`

Ps: everything is updated to the last versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm Alex from Appodeal support team.
It looks like you meet the problem with multidex. This technology works perfect on android 5+, but to use it on older android you need to perform some tricks.

1. Go to main build gradle, find dependencies for project(":android") and add new one: `compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'`.
2. Go to AndroidManifest.xml file and add `android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication"` to the application tag. If your app already uses(extends) the Application class, you can override the attachBaseContext() method and call MultiDex.install(this) to enable multidex.

If this will not help, here tird step:
Download [special SDK buld](https://s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/appodeal-android/custom/1.14.15/Appodeal_Android_1.14.15_NO_DEX.zip), remove all Appodeal related jar files from your project (\android\libs) and past all jar files from special build.

Best regards, Alex Tinekov
Technical Support Specialist

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm not sure I understand how multidex fixes the problem of a class not being found. The error was not about the 65k method limit that multidex does address

Comment: @cricket_007 with multidex all you classes distributed on several dex files. If loading of one of such files was fail, you'll not find some of classes in your application.

Comment: adding the first step was the solution :)